# considering nested state from a data structure using Zustand and Immer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, zustand

**I am having an issue handling state within my application**

### Flow

Prop drilling through 3 components.

-- StartRound.jsx

```
if (roundStarted && selectedRoundId) {
    return (
      <Scorecard
        onGoBack={resetRound}
        courseId={selectedCourse._id}
        selectedTees={selectedTees}
        newRoundId={selectedRoundId}
      />
    );
  }
```

--Scorecard.jsx takes props and creates the scorecard

```
export default function Scorecard({
  onGoBack,
  courseId,
  selectedTees,
  newRoundId,
})
```

--SingleHoleEdit.jsx

```
export default function SingleHoleEdit({ holeScore, roundId, onUpdate })
```

### What I want to happen

1. Player selects a round and a tee color
2. state within StartRound.jsx

```
  const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]); //
  const [selectedCourse, setSelectedCourse] = useState(null);
  const [selectedTees, setSelectedTees] = useState(null);
  const [roundStarted, setRoundStarted] = useState(false);
  const [selectedRoundId, setSelectedRoundId] = useState(null);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
```

3. Scorecard.jsx

```
const [selectedCourse, setSelectedCourse] = useState(null);
  const [selectedTeeColor, setSelectedTeeColor] = useState(null);
  const [courseData, setCourseData] = useState(null);
  const [roundId, setRoundId] = useState(null);
  const [scores, setScores] = useState({}); // This will store hole scores.

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

4. When a player clicks an edit score button from the scorecard  for the current course and current round on a single hole A single hole card is rendered

### Issue

- I cannot figure out how to handle state for this last component.

```
export default function SingleHoleEdit({ holeScore, roundId, onUpdate }) {
  const handleUpdate = (score) => {
    const parsedScore = parseInt(score, 10);
    if (!isNaN(parsedScore)) {
      onUpdate(holeScore.score, parsedScore, roundId);
    } else {
      alert("Please enter a valid score");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="hole-edit">
      <h3>Edit Hole {holeScore.hole}</h3>
      <p>Yardage: {tees?.length || "-"}</p>
      <p>Par: {tees?.par || "-"}</p>
      <p>Handicap: {tees?.handicap || "-"}</p>
      <div className="score-input">
        <label>
          Score:
          <input type="number" min="1" step="1" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleUpdate}>Update Score</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- It is unfinished as a component and does not work as intended.

### Question

- Is utilizing a react use state management like Zustand, Redux, Context, etc the right way to handle this flow state? How would I go about creating state slices for the above and achieve my intended effect?
- I am a brand noob to the idea and implementation of state management so please go easy on me. If you cannot go easy on me, go hard and complicated.

Thank you in advance!!

Described these intentions above.